# What is the meaning of ##* in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

Script:

```
text="//ABC/REC/TLC/SC-prod/1f9/20/00000000957481f9-08d035805a5c94bf"

echo ${text##*/}
```

Here, what is the meaning of 2nd line in the above 2 line script?

Answer (score 12):

This is [Parameter substitution and/or expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSUB2). From the link:

```
${var#Pattern}
```

Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the front end of $var.

```
${var##Pattern}
```

Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the front end of $var.

So `${text##*/}` remove from text everything before the last `/`. It's useful to get the basename of directories for instance.

(There is also `${var%Pattern}`/`${var%%Pattern}` to remove pattern that matches the back end of `$var`)